# i2c device node from device tree is not being probed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, devices, device-tree

I am having trouble troubleshooting my problem where in my i2c pca9546 mux is not being probed by the corresponding driver, i2c-mux-pca954x.c. Here is my device tree node:

```
&i2c0 {
status = "ok";

pca9546@77 {
    compatible = "nxp,pca9546";
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <0>;
    reg = <0x77>;
    status = "okay";
    ....
    ....
```

I ran the command `echo pca9546 0x77 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-0/new_device` resulting in the triggering the probe function and the device being created. I also went through the source code and realized that the driver is unable to find a matching device and that the device tree's nodes are not being recognized as the i2c bus probes for peripheral devices. Anyone know for what may be going on

Comment: Is the device found at the expected address with `i2cdetect -y 0`?

Comment: yes, I ran the command and it showed up on the i2c table. Also when I write to new_device at 0x70 it says probe is successful but to any other address it says probe is not successful.

Comment: I mean at address 0x77